# What are the advantages of silverlight out of browser over wpf or vice versa?

Tags: wpf, silverlight

In fact why would one want a wpf app instead of silverlight out of browser?

Comment: Duplicate here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915323/silverlight-oob-vs-wpf-clickonce

Comment: See previous questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944608/wpf-vs-silverlight,  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/629927/what-is-the-difference-between-wpf-and-silverlight-application and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079812/what-is-the-difference-between-wpf-and-silverlight